Notation for area and Dirichlet energy in Pinkall and Polthier's paper
I am reading Pinkall and Polthier's paper "Computing Discrete Minimal Surfaces and Their Conjugates" and I am a bit lost regarding the notation. There a function $f:\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ parametrising a $2$-surface is given. The author defines the area as:
$$A(f) = \int_{\Omega} Jacobian(f).$$
What is the above supposed to signify? The Jacobian $J_f$ should be given as
$$J_f(u v) = \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ f_u(u,v) & f_v(u,v) \\ | & | \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}, \quad f_u := \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \,\, f_v := \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}.$$
Is it supposed to be the expression for the unsigned area:
$$A(f) = \int_{\Omega} \sqrt{\det[(J_f(u,v))^T(J_f(u,v))]}\,du\,dv = \int_{\Omega} \sqrt{\|f_u(u,v)\|^2\|f_v(u,v)\|^2 - 2f_u(u,v)\cdot f_v(u,v)}\, du dv?$$
Or is it supposed to be the signed area:
$$A(f) = \int_{\Omega} \det[N_1(f(u,v)), \ldots , N_{n-2}(f(u,v)), f_u(u,v), f_v(u,v)] \, dudv?$$
Where $N_1, \ldots, N_{n-2}$ provide an orthonormal basis for the space orthogonal to $span(f_u, f_v)$.
Next they define the Dirichlet energy
$$E_D(f) =\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla f|^2.$$
Later on the authors discuss the same but wrt Riemannian manifolds $(N,h)$ and $(M,g)$ with metrics $g$ and $h$, and $f:\Omega \subset N \to M$, i.e., now $N$ plays the role of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M$ plays the role of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the Dirichlet energy is defined as:
$$E_D(f) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} |\nabla f|^2_g.$$
They elaborate that $|\nabla f|^2_g=Tr\, g(\partial f, \partial f)$ which I assume is $Tr(J_f^TJ_f)$ in Euclidean space:
$$E_D(f) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} Tr(J_f(u,v)^T J_f(u,v))\, du dv = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} \|f_u(u,v)\|^2 + \|f_v(u,v)\|^2\, dudv.$$
They state that it is well known that $A(f(M)) \leq E_D(f)$. Is $A(f(M))$ supposed to be just $A(f)$ here? I know that $f:\Omega \to M$, but I cannot make sense of $f(M)$. They also note that:
$$E_D(f) - A(f(M)) = E_C(f) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} |D^{90} f_u - f_v|^2,$$
which I interpret to mean :
$$\|D^{90} f_u - f_v\|^2 = \|f_u\|^2 + \|f_v\|^2 - 2 f_u^T D^{-90} f_v.$$
The later then implies that the integrand of $A(f(M))$ is $f_u^T D^{-90} f_v$. This is anti-symmetric in $f_u, f_v$ so I suppose $A(f)$ ought to have been the signed area and not the unsigned one.
At some point they start discussing a map $f:(T_1,g) \to (T_2, h)$ between two triangulations $T_1, T_2$ (I believe they switched $g$ and $h$ when compared to the $f:\Omega\subset (N,h) \to (M,g)$ setting in the beginning). And then also the maps between individual triangles $f_i : (\Delta_{i,1}, g) \to (\Delta_{i,2}, h)$. Then they define the Dirichlet energy as
$$E_D(f_i) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{(\Delta_{i}, g)} |\nabla_g f_i|^2_h.$$
Here they say that $\nabla_g$ is the derivative w.r.t. the metric $g$. Do they mean that $\nabla_g f$ is the gradient wrt the inner product given by $g$, i.e., $df(u,v)(y,z) = \langle\nabla f(u,v), (y,z)\rangle_g$, or in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with inner product $\langle (u,v), (y,z) \rangle_g = (u,v)^T G (y,z)$ we have $\nabla f(u,v) = G^{-1}J^T_f(u,v)$.
So I suppose the final expression in Euclidean space is
$$|\nabla_g f|^2_h =\langle \nabla_g f, \nabla_g f\rangle_h = Tr(\nabla_g f^T H \nabla_g f)
= Tr(J_f G^{-1} H G^{-1} J_f^T)?$$
As a side remark - are the gradients equal for the two energies despite of those not being equal except for conformal $f$, i.e.,  $\nabla_f A(f) = -\frac{\kappa_1 + \kappa_2}{2}\vec{n}$ and $\nabla_f E_D(f) = \Delta_M f$ agree up to a constant of $2$ since $\Delta_M f = -(\kappa_1 + \kappa_2)\vec{n}$? Are there other energies that result in the same gradient?

This to me is an exercise. Everything follows from the geometry. You should be able (perhaps after a long struggle) to figure this all out yourself. The idea is to work it all out using your own approach and notation instead of theirs. You should at least try and then post here again after you’ve made more progress.

@Deane I wrote what I figured out myself, the questions is whether what I worked out above is correct. It's a question about notation. Maybe it was unclear from my question but half of the above is what I tried and is not in the paper. I'll try to edit it to make ut clearer.

Try to write the question without referring to the paper or the formulas in it, not even the formula for $A(f)$. You can assume that it's oriented area.
